# ABSPATH not working! Any idea why?

Tags: include, paths

This is what in my wp-config.php :

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

I am calling from plugin/pluginName directory to :

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/user.php');
```

But it is returning:

```
Warning: require_once(ABSPATHwp-includes/user.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/------/wp-content/plugins/---/---.php on line 43

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-includes/user.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/------/wp-content/plugins/---/---.php on line 43
```

Any idea why I am having this error? Any solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you running your script directly? If so, you need to load WP before you can use its constants. Or at least include wp-config...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run it directly as a cron. How can I use it to run script directly?

Comment: It's telling you right here: "ABSPATHwp-includes/user.php". You need a slash in there. "ABSPATH/wp-includes/user.php:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need that class included, and your script is located in the plugin directory, like `/wp-content/plugins/pluginName/script.php`, then you can do:

```
require realpath('../../../wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
```

Comment: Anyway, I was able to load it putting the full path (realpath). Thanks. But I don't understand, why ABSPATH is not working! It should be working.

Comment: How is supposed to work if you're not including the file that defines that constant?